# Exporting to CSV creates displaced rows and way too many

Tags: csv, export

So I have maybe less than 150 total products but my CSV file is reaching 900 rows. Additionally there are displaced rows with some things tripled or doubled.

Is there a way to clean this up before exporting? Like a missed setting/option that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Do you have more than one store view? Andreas von Studnitz describes here the format: http://www.integer-net.com/2012/04/04/importing-products-with-the-import-export-interface/ After understanding the format, I *think* your question needs to be rethought. So the question is *WHAT* do you want to export? But this ist just a guess.

Comment: If I could only export product name and price, and have 2 columns and 150 rows then that is everything I'm hoping for. The last thing I want to do is import all this extra stuff and have it mess everything that is correct.

Comment: I think magento can't do this but it should be easy possible, when you just order by SKU and remove all rows which don't have a sku, then you remove all columns except name and price.

Comment: Wow you did not answer that question... They're asking why it makes a crap csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a version up the 1.5 you could find in System -> Import/Export -> Dataflow Profiles the way to personalize your output.
You can select one of the predefined profiles to help you get started.
In first place I recommend you to use the Excel XML export format instead of CSV, that's simplify the commas o semicolon you could have in your content (in File Information).
You can select the attributes you want to add to your output file in the 
Data Format section. Under the "Export" option change the "All fields" to "Only mapped fields", after that yo can select which fields you want to include in your file.